# Is there a template file to list all terms of a given custom taxonomy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, template-hierarchy

Suppose we registered the `composers` and the `interprets` custom taxonomies.

The `composers` taxonomy could have the following terms:

- Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart
- Ludwig van Beethoven
- Richard Wagner

The `interprets` taxonomy could have the following terms:

- Glenn Gould
- Daniel Barenboim
- Vienna State Opera

I am wondering whether the WordPress template hierarchy has a special file , like `taxonomy-terms.php`, to list taxonomy terms with a simple loop:

```
<?php
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    the_title();
endwhile;
?>
```

This would print (assuming the `/%postname%/` permalink setting):

- `Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart`, `Ludwig van Beethoven`, `Richard Wagner` when viewing `example.com/composers`
- `Glenn Gould`, `Daniel Barenboim`, `Vienna State Opera` when viewing `example.com/interprets`

If not, I would like to know the best way to implement this. I would create a page template for each taxonomy, `template-composers-terms.php` and `template-interprets-terms.php` and list terms using something like the following code:

```
<?php
/* Template Name: List of composers */ // or 'List of interprets'
$terms = get_terms( 'composers' ); // or get_terms( 'interprets' )
foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
    echo $term->name;
endforeach;
?>
```

Then, I create two pages, "Composers" and "Interprets", to which I respectively assigned the "List of composers" and "List of interprets" templates.

I'm not very comfortable using this method, because it requires creating a new file for each taxonomy.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the same file in `template-composers-terms.php` and `template-interprets-terms.php` like that :

```
<?php
/* Template Name: List of composers */

$tax = "composer";
require "include/file_which_does_all_the_work.php";
```

and if the page slug is the same that the taxonomy slug, you can save the line `$tax = ...` with that in the included file :

```
$tax = $GLOBALS["wp_query"]->query["pagename"];
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an error with the code, I think...
as the get_terms support arrays as parameters.
So the best way to do this, I think is:
1- create your template-composers-terms.php 
2- Include them in the page using:

```
<?php get_template_part('template','composers-terms') ?>
```

and finally in your newly created file put:

```
<?php
/* Template Name: List of composers or 'List of interprets' */
$terms = get_terms(array(
         'taxonomy' => 'composers', // make sure it is the taxonomy key passed at the  register_taxonomy function.
         'hide_empty' => false
 );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
    echo $term->name;
endforeach;
?>
```